# How to remove every first specific character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, csv, format

Im looking for the right regular expression to remove every first specific character in each new line.

Input:

```
S17,E108,736
S17,E109,737
```

Output that I wish:

```
S17E108,736
S17E109,737
```

Im working in a 100 line long CSV-File with Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the following "*Find what*": `^([^,]+),`
- Use the following "*Replace with*": `\1`
- Select "*Search Mode*" as "*Regular Expression*"
- Click "*Replace All*"

[image: replace]

Have a play here: https://regex101.com/r/OEKqGM/1

Answer (score 0):

Well, using your example, this worked for me:

```
Find What: ([^,]+),(.+)
Replace With: $1$2
```

Replace All